# gcc/ld script ignores the start adress of the .text section and adds a lot of junk to my binary

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, i386

I am trying to build the following really small C program into a raw binary file:

```
asm ("call sys_main\n"                  // Immediately run sys_main at start of code
     "__asm_loop_halt:\n"
     "jmp __asm_loop_halt\n");          // Then halt

int sys_main() {
    short *addr = (short*) 0x08b000;    // Address start of EGA-VRAM
    *addr       = 0x0f41;               // Write white 'A' on black to screen
}
```

Because I am trying to create a raw binary I have to use a linker script `gcc -std=gnu99 -Os -nostdlib -m32 -march=i386 -ffreestanding -Wl,--nmagic,--script=386.ld -o test test.c`:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x0500 :
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.data);
        *(.bss);
        *(.rodata);
    }
    _heap = ALIGN(4);
}
```

The script is supposed to tell the linker that the code starts running at 0x500 and that it should only create a binary file. However when I disassemble the binary, I get:

```
00000000  E802000000        call dword 0x7
00000005  EBFE              jmp short 0x5
00000007  55                push ebp
00000008  89E5              mov ebp,esp
0000000A  66C70500B0080041  mov word [dword 0x8b000],0xf41
         -0F
00000013  5D                pop ebp
00000014  C3                ret
00000015  0000              add [eax],al
00000017  001400            add [eax+eax],dl
......
```

Appearantly the linker still took 0x0 as the start address of the code and also added a bunch of random data behind the last senseful 'ret' instruction, that is in total 4 times as big as the code.

What is this data, why is it there and what did I do wrong to have my code start at 0x0?

Edit: Thanks to Eugene's tip with the map I discovered that the bytes behind the `.text` section are `.eh_frame` responsible for exception handling which can easily removed by calling `gcc` with `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`.

Comment: Don't "disassemble the binary". Look in the `map` file instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks a lot. The map helped me realize that the additional bytes are .eh_frame which I could simply remove with the `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` flag. The map also says that .text starts indeed at 0x500, but if I just load this raw binary into RAM with a custom bootloader, wouldn't the first call instruction still jump to 0x7 instead of 0x507?

Comment: Can't check it right now, but I believe the numbers you see are relative offsets.